# Timedelta of datetime object and timezone object

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, pytz

I have a string datetime in YY/M/D/H which is already casted to PST timezone and saved. While reading it I am doing the following

```
submitted_time = '2020/02/13/11/16'
submitted_datetime = datetime.strptime(submitted_time, '%Y/%m/%d/%H/%M')
```

This time is already in PST timezone and to calculate the timedifference I tried doing the following :

```
from pytz import timezone
pacific = timezone('America/Los_Angeles')
today = datetime.now().astimezone(pacific)
```

But today - submitted_datetime won't work.  I get the following error:

> *** TypeError: can't subtract offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes

Is there a way I can get this working ? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

With the code you provide, I doubt `submitted_time` will be interpreted as timezone aware, let alone `PST`. If you do convert it to a timezone aware datetime object, then the substraction works:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone
submitted_time = datetime.strptime('2020/02/13/11/16', '%Y/%m/%d/%H/%M')
pacific = timezone('America/Los_Angeles')
today = datetime.now().astimezone(pacific)
submitted_time = submitted_time.astimezone(pacific)
print(today - submitted_time)
```

Output:

```
5 days, 4:50:57.251801
```